# Filling online forms

Tags: jquery, combobox

I'm using jquery to quickly fill some forms at work, I don't really know much about what I'm actually doing, but what I have seems to work just fine. There is just this one small problem, these forms have a few instances where there are 3 comboboxes, where the content of the second and third one depends on the choice made in the first one. Problem is, they get populated only after I manually select an option from the first combobox, meaning when I try using this:

```
$("[name=region2] [value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
$("[name=district2] [value='204']").attr("selected", "selected");
$("[name=townIdentification2] [value='1204826001']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

only the first combobox will be successfully filled, while the other two will remain empty. So, what do I have to do to get them populated? Do I have to like simulate mouseclicks?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger click event using your code in jQuery, use:

```
$("[name=region2] [value='1']").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the first checkbox changes, then you can act based on that event.

```
$('#YourCheckBox').change(function() {
    // Do something      
});
```

Comment: I already figured I could populate them if I add change at the end. Like "$("[name=region2] [value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");.trigger("change");", this way they get populated, but it takes so long that before they do, the script ends and so nothing gets chosen.